# Google App Engine : InitialContext class is not supported

Tags: google-app-engine

I use the code of a dynamic web project to make a ***Google App Engine project***.
Now, sometimes I had in my code : `ctx = new InitialContext();
            SuggestServices services = (SuggestServices) ctx.lookup("SuggestServices");`

to invoke services from another container.

But ***InitialContext*** is not supported in GAE.

What should I do to invoke services now ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just that InitialContext class is not supported, JNDI is entirely not supported, so use another mechanism for registering and injecting objects, for example Guice.